# ActiveAdmin modify existing controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, controller, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin I am trying to edit instance variables in the `show` view. I have tried to do this with the following code per the [ActiveAdmin docs](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modify_the_controller):

```
#admin/job.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Job do
...
controller do
    def show
        @job = Job.find(params[:id])
        @comment  = Comment.new
        @comments = @job.comments
    end
end
...
```

This is resulting in a `nilClass` error when I try to use those variables in the ActiveAdmin `show` because they aren't really defined. Am I misunderstanding how the controller actions should be edited?

Comment: With the `@comments` variable do you want appear the comments on the show page?

Comment: yes, they appear at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the show block not the show action in the controller:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/6-show-pages.md#customize-the-show-page

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do
  show do |job|
    attributes_table do
      row :attributes_of_job
    end
    #you can also reach the comments like this: job.comments
    active_admin_comments
  end
end
```

Comment: I already have a show block, but I want to feed extra instance variables to it. Normally I would do this by declaring instance variables in the controller's show action. I thought that was what the docs I linked in the OP were explaining how to do but it isn't working

Comment: job.comments isn't working? You don't need instance variable.. you can reach the record through the job reference in the show block with all the associated records.